# delete text when action button is clicked

Tags: r, shiny

I want to delete a textOutput on the mainPanel using shiny. When the app starts there should be the text e.g. "welcome...". By clicking the action Button a datatable is printed and the text should be deleted and not written underneath the table. I tried it with something like this (see below) but `output$mytable2` can't be used as an indicator (

> Error: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.

). I have not included the whole code because I think this might be very basic but I can´t find a solution. (I also tried "`removeUI`" to remove `textOutput()` from ui inside the `observeEvent` function of the button but this deleted everything)

```
ui :  [...]
        mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput('mytable2'),
        textOutput("welcome1")

server: [...]
        output$mytable2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
          (DT::datatable(datasetInput(),rownames=FALSE))
           }) 

          fg<-reactive({text1<-c("Welcome..","") 
          fg<-2
          if (is.null(output$mytable2)){fg=1}
          return(text1[fg])}) 

        output$welcome1 <- renderText({ fg() })...
```

Any easy Ideas? Just how to manage this exemplatory? Many thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at the `shinyjs` package and hide the textoutput. You can check [this](http://deanattali.com/shinyjs/example) link .

Comment: Thank you I will check this :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this solution:

**ui.R**

```
uiOutput("text)
actionButton("button1", "Go")
```

**server.R**

```
output$text <- renderUI({if(input$button1 == 0){paste("Welcome...")} else{return()}})
```

When `actionButton` is not pressed, it has a value of **0**, after pressing it, value changes to **1**.

Therefore i have used the `if...else..` statement saying if button has value **0**, then show the text "Welcome...", if it changes to **1**, return nothing.